# How to back up my git changes?

Tags: git

`git diff > backup.diff` does not work for me because as it will only get the diffs, it won't get the new files that I've created on the working tree.

`git stash` also does not work for me as it will save the changes on the repo, but if somehow my computer breaks then I won't have access to these changes anymore.

Committing these changes is also not a good idea since these are unfinished changes.

So the question is, what is a reliable and practical way of backing up my changes and saving them somewhere outside the repository?

Comment: This might sound a little simple but could you not just copy and paste the files (excluding git files) to a different location on your computer or online storage?

Comment: @DanLister this is totally not a good idea for me, what if it's a big project with a complex directory structure, copying only the modified files will take some unnecessary time

Comment: @DanLister also, what if I'm backing it up for working on a new feature, then I will paste the copied changes back again but I've committed a new change after that copy.

Comment: @user1091856 You might want to look at using git stash or git patch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way git offers to store unfinished changed remotely is to work on them on a feature specific branch (so they don't interfere with the rest of your development), and commit them even when they are not finished. This allows you to push the changes to the remote repository, which gives you a backup off your computer.

Comment: +1 you can then use the magical powers of [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) to squash those feature related commits into one/several succinct commits when you merge the branch.